# Detail Link in Email Template

Tags: email, email-template

Maybe I missed it somewhere but I haven't been able to find it anywhere.

So here is the question:

I am using Detail Link in email template and the email is send via Workflow to notify Record Creator. We have internal users and external users (community) that can create records. The detail link will send correct URL based on if the user is internal or external (community has different prefix). It's working fine I am just wondering based on what Salesforce determinate if the user is community or not. The URL is generated only based on User Licence or its based on something else?

Thank you.